# How to write image in specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, imagemagick

I am trying to add a profile picture in a specific directory in my project: *~Images/ProfilePicture*

```
_context.People.Add(person);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                if (person.ProfilePicture != null)
                {
                    string[] photoName = person.ProfilePicture.FileName.Split('.');
                    var imageName = $"{person.PersonId}.{photoName[photoName.Length - 1]}";
                    string uploaded = Path.Combine("~Images", "ProfilePicturePerson");
                    string filepath = Path.Combine(uploaded, imageName);

                    //return MagickImage
                    var profilePic = ImageStuff.HandleImage(person.ProfilePicture);
                    //error
                    profilePic.Write(imageName);
                    person.ProfilePictureName = filepath;
                }
                
                _context.SaveChanges();
```

I want the `MagickImage.write` function to create the file in the specified directory instead of creating the image in the main directory of the project

Answer (score 0):

Your should inyect IHostEnvironment in your service like this:

```
    public class Service : IService
    {
        private readonly IHostEnvironment _environment;
        
        public SftpService(IHostEnvironment environment)
        {   
            _environment = environment;
        }

        public void DownloadFile()
        {
             var _fileName = "PictureName";
             var remoteFilePath= "Path where is your image";

             //if your service is in your main proyect
             var localFilePath = Path.Combine($" 
             {_environment.ContentRootPath}\\Images\\ProfilePicture\\             
             {_fileName}");

             //if your service is in your other proyect. For example Application
             var localFilePath = 
             Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath.Replace("MS.Core", 
             "MS.Aplication"), $"\\Images\\ProfilePicture\\{_fileName}");

             try
                {
                   client.Connect();
                   using var s = File.Create(localFilePath);

                   client.DownloadFile(remoteFilePath, s);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                   client.Disconnect();
                }
        }
    }
```

This example is assuming that the image is in some external service but you could take it as a guide perhaps.

Comment: I injected the ```IHostEnvironment```, I am able to get the image but I have to resize it and compress it, then rewrite the file, when it is rewriting, it saves it on the root path, unlike what I want to save it in another folder in the project.

Comment: Are you writting the correct path in localPath variable??

Comment: The thing here is there is no way to set the path, It is just put in the root path